# Google map Geolocation formatting address

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I'm using Geo location service with Gmap Api and i would like to know ,how do i have to format data address ?

i have to format addresses according to local server location.

which is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the result back from geolocation, reverse geocode:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder